# Is there a commonly used short name for "squared Euclidean distance"?

Tags: terminology, euclidean-geometry, norms

In an optimization program I pass around distance values quite often. In my case these are simple 2D Euclidean distances $\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$. Since I want to perform the square root calculation only at the end of all operations, I pass only squared distances $(\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2)$ around in the program.

Right now I'm using the variable name `dist` for distances and `dist2` for squared distances, where `dist2` is intended to mean `dist`$^2$.

Is this a mathematically good choice of naming, or is there a more commonly used name for this?

(Such as `sqdist`? Or `sed` = squared Euclidean distance? Or `sos` = sum of squares?)

Comment: you can name it anything you want in a computer program, as long as you don't use the same symbol twice.

Comment: in statistics it is known as variance ...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Was this meant to be a helpful comment? Anyway, from a software engineering perspective, I strongly disagree. Choosing good variable names is especially important in computer programs, especially if these are meant to be reviewed, extended and maintained by other people.

Answer (score 5):

Norm Wildberger calls it *[quadrance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry#Quadrance)*. But at this point I wouldn't say that's a commonly used name for it.